# Is this possible to contract tensor acted by d'Alembert operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I am a physics student and I work on General Relativity in this day and age. I have a little mathematical understanding in Differential geometry.

However, when I have to counter d'Alembert operator in my work, I do not find much information about this object.

As I know, we can write:
$$\mathop\Box\equiv g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\equiv g_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\equiv \partial^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}\equiv\partial_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}$$
Now, it acts on a tensor-like $h^{\gamma\lambda}$ with $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$ for $h_{\mu\nu}<<1$:
$$\mathop\Box h^{\gamma\lambda}=\partial_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}h^{\gamma\lambda}$$
Here the question, if I multiply both sides by an metric $\eta_{\alpha\beta}$, is $\eta_{\alpha\beta}$ able to contract $h^{\gamma\lambda}$ like this
$$\eta_{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}h^{\gamma\lambda}=\partial_{\nu}\partial^{\nu}h^{\lambda}_{\beta} \quad\mathrm{if}\quad\alpha=\gamma$$
I think it depend on specific $\nu$ compare with $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\lambda$, right?

Suppose that $h^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetrical.

Comment: If you're working in general (not special) relativity then you need those partial derivatives to be covariant ones. You also have some errors in the indices - it should be $g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu = \nabla_\mu \nabla^{\color{red} \nu}$.

Comment: Thank you. I got some typo over there. Edited.

Comment: About the covariant derivatives, do you mean that every extension should be represented by some Christoffel symbols? Oh, it's right for GR, however, in this case (I do not mention here), I'm considering $h^{\mu\nu}$ small. Sorry for lacking information.

Comment: I should have written $\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu$ in my comment above, but looks like you picked up my point. Anyway, assuming $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric in standard coordinates, it certainly can commute past $\partial_\nu \partial^\nu$; but you'd need to sum over $\alpha = \gamma$ to make $\eta_{\alpha \beta} h^{\gamma \lambda}$ equal to $h^\lambda_\beta$.